# Access to ctypes **argv from binary file through Python

Tags: python, struct, ctypes

I have the following struct output in a binary file from hashcat restore file:

```
typedef struct
{
  uint32_t  version_bin;
  char      cwd[256];
  uint32_t  argc;
  char      **argv;
  uint32_t  pid;

  uint32_t  devices_cnt;

  uint32_t  dictpos;
  uint32_t  maskpos;

  uint64_t *pw_off;
  uint64_t *pw_num;
  uint64_t  pw_cur;

  uint32_t  digests_cnt;
  uint32_t  digests_done;
  uint     *digests_shown;

  uint32_t  salts_cnt;
  uint32_t  salts_done;
  uint     *salts_shown;

  float     ms_running;

} restore_data_t;
```

I'm trying to import the raw data and parse it with a Python script using the ctypes data structure as follows:

```
class RestoreStruct(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("version_bin", c_uint32),
        ("cwd", c_char*256),
        ("argc", c_uint32),
        ("argv", POINTER(POINTER(c_char))), 
        ("pid", c_uint32),
        ("devices_cnt", c_uint32),
        ("dictpos", c_uint32),
        ("maskpos", c_uint32),
        ("pw_off", POINTER(c_uint64)),  
        ("pw_NUM", POINTER(c_uint64)),  
        ("pw_CUR", c_uint64),
        ("digests_cnt", c_uint32),
        ("digests_done", c_uint32),
        ("digests_shown", POINTER(c_uint32)),   
        ("salts_cnt", c_uint32),
        ("salts_done", c_uint32),
        ("salts_shown", POINTER(c_uint*30)),    
        ("ms_running", c_float)

        ]

with open("cudaHashcat.restore", "rb") as restore_file:

    status = []
    struct = RestoreStruct()
    while restore_file.readinto(struct) == sizeof(struct):
        status.append((struct.version_bin, struct.cwd, struct.argc, struct.argv, \
                    struct.pid, struct.devices_cnt, struct.dictpos, struct.maskpos, struct.pw_off, \
                    struct.pw_NUM, struct.pw_CUR, struct.digests_cnt, struct.digests_done, struct.digests_shown, \
                    struct.salts_cnt, struct.salts_done, struct.salts_shown, struct.ms_running))



    print struct._fields_[0][0], status[0][0]
    print struct._fields_[1][0], status[0][1]
    print struct._fields_[2][0], status[0][2]
    print struct._fields_[3][0], status[0][3]
    print struct._fields_[4][0], status[0][4]
    print struct._fields_[5][0], status[0][5]
    print struct._fields_[6][0], status[0][6]
    print struct._fields_[7][0], status[0][7]
    print struct._fields_[8][0], status[0][8]
    print struct._fields_[9][0], status[0][9]
    print struct._fields_[10][0], status[0][10]
    print struct._fields_[11][0], status[0][11]
    print struct._fields_[12][0], status[0][12]
    print struct._fields_[13][0], status[0][13]
    print struct._fields_[14][0], status[0][14]
    print struct._fields_[15][0], status[0][15]
    print struct._fields_[16][0], status[0][16]
    print struct._fields_[17][0], status[0][17]
```

This issue I'm having is how to access the data in the pointer ctypes (argv,pw_off, etc)? I've tried the "contents", but I get "NULL pointer access" error. argv should be an array of char arrays, and the others should be a simple pointer to an int.

How would I access the actual data that the pointers are addressing? Am I completely off on how I'm going about this?

Here is a base64 encoded version of the restore file:

> ZQAAAEU6XG9jbEhhc2hjYXQtMS4wMQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJAAAACBdvAHwiAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>   AAAAAAAAAAAAAAABACgBAAAAAA8AAAAFAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEDPnkYAAAAAY3VkYUhh
>   c2hjYXQzMgotbQoxMDAwCi1hCjAKLXIKcnVsZXNccmljaF9wd19ydWxlcy5ydWxlCi4uXHBsYWlu
>   X3RleHRfaGFzaC50eHQKLi5cMTZfV2Fsa19taW4udHh0Cv//JwEAAAAAAAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAQAA
>   AAAAAAABAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAAAAAAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

As pointed out in the comments it looks like the argv values are stored in the file as plain text. My issue is still how to read this information into a struct properly. All of the other values in the restore struct are read in and stored correctly in the python object, but the code above. Any pointer structure though doesn't read in as easy.

Comment: yes the struct is correct. I'm using version 1.01. v1.2 is in beta only. I can post a sample restore file next week. If the file uses the arrays directly would I just use the c_char_p type or the c_char*sizeof(array)?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out. I think my problem is I'm not familiar with trying to read this type of data into a python object. I'm using the readinto function to copy the whole struct into the above defined RestoreStruct object. If you run my code above with the restore file I get the values you're talking about, but I'm still not sure how to parse out the argv array. ms_running is updating I just didn't print it out in the code above. I'll edit to reflect that value.

Comment: Thanks I'll give that go. I'll post a working version when I come up with a solution. I agree the documentation is lacking.

Comment: Just so I'm clear. Instead of using the all-at-once readinto method above just read the whole file into a byte array and parse the bytes after 328?

Comment: Thanks! I used your suggestions to get the argv values. I still don't know what hashcat is writing to the space with **argv though. O'well. Is there a way to give you credit for the answer on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking eryksun's advice here what I did to get the argv values.

```
class RestoreStruct(Structure):

    _fields_ = [
        ("version_bin", c_uint32),
        ("cwd", c_char*256),
        ("argc", c_uint32),
        ("argv", POINTER(POINTER(c_char))), 
        ("pid", c_uint32),
        ("devices_cnt", c_uint32),
        ("dictpos", c_uint32),
        ("maskpos", c_uint32),
        ("pw_off", POINTER(c_uint64)),  
        ("pw_NUM", POINTER(c_uint64)),  
        ("pw_CUR", c_uint64),
        ("digests_cnt", c_uint32),
        ("digests_done", c_uint32),
        ("digests_shown", POINTER(c_uint32)),   
        ("salts_cnt", c_uint32),
        ("salts_done", c_uint32),
        ("salts_shown", POINTER(c_uint*30)),    
        ("ms_running", c_float)

        ]

with open("cudaHashcat.restore", "rb") as restore_file:

    status = []
    struct = RestoreStruct()
    restore_file.readinto(struct)
    rest = restore_file.read()

    print struct.version_bin
    # Print rest of variables that are not pointers

    print rest.splitlines()[0:struct.argc]    # Prints a list structure of argv values
```